# What's the strategy in game engines to perform secure state changes?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, opengl-es, concurrency

I created a run loop in OpenGL ES which is called by a CADisplayLink at 60fps. AFAIK CADisplayLink calls it's target on a background thread.

I have about 100 state variables which are used by the run loop.

The problem: From the main thread, I want to change state variables which are used in the run loop to draw something. A frame must be drawn only after all state variables have been set to their target values.

I am afraid that at some point when I change a state variable, and I'm not done yet changing them all (in one big method in same run loop iteration on main thread), for example position of a geometric shape, there is multi-threading related crash or problem where the CADisplayLink will kick in right in the middle of my method that updates the state variables, and then draw garbage or crash.

Obviously when I just use synchronized or atomic properties it won't help because it is still not transactional. I think I need transactions.

My naive approach is this:

Instance variable read by run loop:

```
BOOL updatingState;
```

The run loop method will skip drawing if updatingState reads YES.

Then before starting to change state I set it to YES. And when everything is changed, I set it back to NO.

Now of course, problem: What if -while I am changing this- the run loop method is reading the values?

How do game engines deal with this problem? What kind of locking mechanisms do they have so the changing of the state variables can be finished before the next frame is going to be drawn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find a read-copy-update strategy useful. One possible implementation is that each object actually contains two copies of the rendering parameters and an atomic flag is used to tell the rendering thread which to use. You will need to use a read memory barrier in the renderer to make sure that the flag is read before reading any of the parameters and a write memory barrier in the updater thread to make sure that all of the parameter updates are written before flipping the flag.

Comment: A better strategy is to have a single top level pointer or object reference or array index and two complete state trees. The top level pointer should be read and written using atomic instructions. The read-only tree is used to create the new state and the render engine also reads from the read-only tree. When the new state is ready, the top level pointer/index/reference is updated.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way how this is done is that all state updates happen at each run loop iteration, before the drawing is done. That is, the run loop looks schematically like this:

```
updateState();
draw();
```

With this model, the drawing only happens after the a consistent state has been reached.

For this to work, you need to have a model where events such as key presses are polled for on each updateState() instead of happening asychronously, and a time measurement on each iteration to tell you how much time elapsed since the last frame.

I can't help you how this is realized in the concrete case of iOS programming, though, as I don't know anything about that. But I hope I could point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a common problem in concurrency, so there are several ways to do it:

1. Use an immutable state class to hold the state variables.
2. Use a locking mechanism (if an immutable class cannot be used) to protect the state variables.
3. Have multiple states which you can modify, but only one is "active." This will allow you to reuse states and it will reduce copying and memory allocation.

Additionally, consider this situation:

Thread 1. Start drawing something.
Thread 1. Read 1/2 of the state 01 parameters (first state).
Thread 2. Swap out state 01 with state 02 (second state).
Thread 1. Reads the other 1/2 of state 02, but it's different from the state 01 parameters.

So the best option is not to allow the update of the state during the drawing, so option 3 might be the best way to do it because you would simply pick up the latest state and draw it. Let's say you have two states: `drawingState` and `nonDrawingState`. In your draw function you will always use the `drawingState` to draw while other threads modify the `nonDrawingState`. Once you're done drawing, then you can swap the states and continue drawing with the latest state modifications.